# stop iTunes from auto-playing after import

Tags: itunes

I drag a movie onto the iTunes icon. iTunes imports the movie, and then begins playing it for me automatically.

How do I stop it from playing the movie automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

according to [this macworld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1135501/itunes8prefs.html), do the following in Terminal, quit & relaunch iTunes

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunes play-songs-while-importing -bool FALSE
```

Comment: Doesn't work for drag-and-drop of mp4 video into iTunes 11.3 (54) 64-bit on Mac OS X 9.4 Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> inside iTunes instead of drag and drop, at least that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2761090?start=0&tstart=0) on the Apple Support forums that mentions your problem.  Here's what you can try:

> The most consistent way I've found to solve this is to drop your files
>   into the "Automatically add to iTunes folder."   How I do it on a Mac:
>   Navigate to Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/ Seconday click on
>   "Automatically Add to iTunes" Select "create alias." - this makes a
>   shortcut, for those who didn't know Click and drag the new shortcut
>   you just made to your desktop or launchbar or somewhere else where it
>   is more convenient for you. Drag any new files that you want to add to
>   iTunes onto that from now on, if you don't want them to autoplay.

Another user suggests that you can use the shortcut of <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>, or just use the open dialog to open your media.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to drag the movie or song to their respective folders in your library, and then use the file - import method in itunes to add it to your library without having it play when it's done importing.